# MYSQL and COUNT IF

Tags: sql, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH42K.jpg)i have folowing table with emails an integer

I would have to add up all the integers and group them with the email to get a result EMAIL | COUNT. is something like that possible?

I try

```
SELECT 
      email,
      MAX( COUNT( IF( 500_K \>= 1, 1, NULL)) 
        OR COUNT( IF( 1_Million \>= 1, 1, NULL)) 
        OR COUNT( IF( 2_Million \>= 1, 1, NULL)) ) 
   FROM 
      user__abzeichen


and

SELECT
      email, 
      COUNT( 500_K \> 0
          OR 1_Million  \> 0
          OR 2_Million  \> 0
          OR 5_Million  \> 0
          OR 10_Million  \> 0
          OR Faehnrich  \> 0
          OR Kapitaen  \> 0
          OR Admiral \> 0
          OR Thrall \> 0
          OR Jarl \> 0
          OR Koenig \> 0
          OR Explosiv \> 0
          OR Roter_Stern \> 0
          OR Roter_Teufel \> 0
          OR 1_Jahr \> 0
          OR 2_Jahre \> 0
          OR 5_Jahre \> 0
          OR 10_Jahre \> 0
          OR Unter_10_Prozent \> 0
          OR Unter_5_Prozent \> 0
          OR Unter_1_Prozent \> 0
          OR Ehrenmitglied_1 \> 0
          OR Ehrenmitglied_2 \> 0
          OR Ehrenmitglied_3 \> 0
          OR The_Big_Cut \> 0
          OR Seelenbaum \> 0 ) AS ANZ 
   FROM 
      user__abzeichen
```

Comment: You really should think about redesign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the value is strictly int.

```
 select email, sum(`500_K` + `1_Million` + `2_Million` + `5_Million` + `10_Million` + `Faehnrich`....So on) as count
 from user__abzeichen group by email
```

Simple as that no need to complicate.

Comment: that works, thank you very much. the simplest solution is always the last to be found

Comment: @Thommy then you have to upvote and accept this as your answer!

Comment: @Thommy Great, as suggested by bon please accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

select email, SUM('500_K'

- '1_Million'
- '2_Million'
- '5_Million'
- '10_Million'
- 'Faehnrich'
  ) as count
  from user__abzeichen group by email

that at al rows 518[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXcRV.jpg)

Comment: This is a comment and since you have no rep to post a comment, you can add this as an update to your question/or simply update it.